# NumPy 'ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.'

Tags: python, numpy

I have a script which parses an json web-service and uses parses the fields to add to an Esri File Geodatabase, towards the end of my script I receive the error.  Not sure what the error,  `File "C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.2/websocket-client-0.23.0/websocket-client-0.23.0/examples/JSONSerializer.py", line 43, in <module>
    narr = numpy.array([vehicles],  ndtype)
ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.` means.

Script:

```
import json
import jsonpickle
import requests
import arcpy
import numpy

fc = "C:\MYLATesting.gdb\MYLA311"
if arcpy.Exists(fc):
  arcpy.Delete_management(fc)

f = open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myla311.json', 'r')

data = jsonpickle.encode( jsonpickle.decode(f.read()) )

url = "https://myla311test.lacity.org/myla311router/mylasrbe/1/QuerySR"
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

decoded = json.loads(r.text)

SRAddress =  decoded['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest'][0]['SRAddress']
latitude = decoded['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest'][0]['Latitude']
longitude =  decoded['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest'][0]['Longitude']

a = {"items":[{SRAddress, latitude, longitude}]}


ndtype = numpy.dtype([
    ('SRAddress', 'S16'),
    ('latitude', 'F48'),
    ('longitude', 'F48')

])

vehicles = []
for item in a['items']:
    vehicles.append(tuple(unicode(item[k] for k in ndtype.names)))

narr = numpy.array([vehicles],  ndtype)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(narr, fc, ['longitude', 'latitude'], sr)


print a.keys()

# parsed_json = json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

# print json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
narr = numpy.array([vehicles],  ndtype)
```

means, create an array, using `ndtype` as the dtype definition, and `[vehicles]` as the data.  `ndtype` defines the `fields`.

`[vehicles]` then should be a list of tuples, and each tuple should have 3 items, e.g. `[(address1, lat1, lon1)]` or `[(a1,la1,lo1), (a2,la2,lo2) ....]`

I think you need to display the value of `vehicles`, and even `[vehicles]` to make sure if fits this pattern.  `a` has this data.  But `vehicles` is created by starting with `[]`, and appending to it.  That means it is already a list. `[vehicles]` is then a list of a list, not a list of tuples.

Without trying to run your code, this change might work, on the assumption that `vehicles` already is the required list of tuples.

```
narr = numpy.array(vehicles,  ndtype)
```

---

Your `[vehicle]`, stripped back is:

```
''.join(x[0])
'<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0D5A3D00>'
```

for example:

```
In [20]: item={'1':'one','2':'two','3':'three'}
In [21]: unicode(item[k] for k in item)
Out[21]: '<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb438e02c>'
```

I think what you want is (assuming the `item` values are byte strings):

```
In [33]: item={'1':b'one','2':b'two','3':b'three'}
In [34]: tuple(item[k].decode() for k in item)
Out[34]: ('three', 'two', 'one')
```

---

In

```
{'items': [set([u'-118.252968', u'34.064937', u'1200 W TEMPLE ST, 90026'])]}
```

that inner structure is a set, not a dictionary.  It is produced by:

```
{SRAddress, latitude, longitude}
```

I'm suprised that `item[k]` works, because sets don't support indexing.

But let's try to build your array with this data:

```
SRAddress = u'1200 W TEMPLE ST, 90026'
latitude=u'34.064937'
longitude=u'-118.252968'
# make a dictionary, not a set
a = {"items":[{'SRAddress':SRAddress, 'latitude':latitude, 'longitude':longitude}]}
vehicles=[]
for item in a['items']:
    vehicles.append(tuple(item[k] for k in ndtype.names))
# [('1200 W TEMPLE ST, 90026', '34.064937', '-118.252968')]
np.array(vehicles, ndtype)
```

But this last produces an error: `TypeError: a float is required`.  That's because `latitude` is a string, but ndtype specifies a float.

A shorter way to construct `vehicles` is (could still be iterative);

```
vehicles = [(SRAddress, float(latitude), float(longitude))]
np.array(vehicles, ndtype)
```

But this produces another problem:

```
array([(b'1200 W TEMPLE ST', (34.064937591552734+0j), (-118.25296783447266+0j))], 
  dtype=[('SRAddress', 'S16'), ('latitude', '<c8'), ('longitude', '<c8')])
```

I don't think you want the `F48` dtype.  `float`, `f48` maybe, or maybe a string.

Comment: You were right about the values of vehicles, my out put is `[(u'<', u'g', u'e', u'n', u'e', u'r', u'a', u't', u'o', u'r', u' ', u'o', u'b', u'j', u'e', u'c', u't', u' ', u'<', u'g', u'e', u'n', u'e', u'x', u'p', u'r', u'>', u' ', u'a', u't', u' ', u'0', u'x', u'0', u'D', u'5', u'A', u'3', u'D', u'0', u'0', u'>')]`  Vehicles actually corresponds to one order request of the address and lat/lng of it, so it will be one row that is writing if that helps.

Comment: I think there's a misplaced `encode`, causing the `tuple` to split a string.  See my additions.

Comment: I do not follow what `In [33]: item={'1':b'one','2':b'two','3':b'three'}
In [34]: tuple(item[k].decode() for k in item)
Out[34]: ('three', 'two', 'one')` means in relation to my code, what would the first line translate to in my context?

Comment: It's just an example of what `item` might look like (a dictionary).   Could you print out a sample of the `a` variable?  Then we wouldn't have to guess its structure.

Comment: `{'items': [set([u'-118.252968', u'34.064937', u'1200 W TEMPLE ST, 90026'])]}`